# Spring-Boot based

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, struts2, playback

How can Spring Boot be integrated with other Java frameworks such as Play or Struts?

I am working on a Java web application using Spring Boot and I would like to know how I can integrate it with other Java frameworks such as Play or Struts. I have looked through the Spring Boot documentation and searched online, but I haven't been able to find any clear guidance on this topic.

Can anyone provide guidance or examples of how to integrate Spring Boot with Play or Struts? Specifically, I am interested in understanding how to handle routing, request handling, and dependency injection when combining these frameworks.

I have tried experimenting with different approaches, but I keep running into issues with conflicting dependencies or incompatible configuration options. I am hoping that someone with more experience in this area can provide some guidance or best practices.

Comment: There's no integration available to Spring Boot. However, if you work with Struts2, then it integrates to Spring via plugin. Merely you can find links to Struts documentation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40932062/573032) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add those dependencies to your pom.xml file?

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Here you also have few articles and documentation about integrating Spring app with Struts:

https://www.baeldung.com/struts-2-intro

https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/spring

I've also found a sample project here:

https://github.com/linux-china/struts2-spring-boot-integration

Comment: The first two links aren't Spring Boot-related. Just adding the dependencies doesn't really do anything.